# Tikz-Network Draw Edge without Node (Invisible Node) Latex

Tags: latex, nodes, edges, tikz

I want to draw an edge from a point below a node, to the node. Here is what I have so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertex[x=0,label=1, size=1.2]{A} \Vertex[x=3,size=1.2,label=2]{B} \Vertex[x=6,size=1.2,label=3]{C}
\Edge[Direct,label=0.4,bend=20,fontscale=1.2](A)(B)
\Edge[Direct,label=0.6,bend=30](A)(C)
\Edge[Direct,label=0.25,bend=20](C)(B)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which yields:

[image: I want to draw an arrow from about 3mm below node 1 directed to node 1]

I want to draw an arrow from about 3mm below node 1 directed to node 1

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertex[x=0,label=1, size=1.2]{A} \Vertex[x=3,size=1.2,label=2]{B} \Vertex[x=6,size=1.2,label=3]{C}
\Edge[Direct,label=0.4,bend=20,fontscale=1.2](A)(B)
\Edge[Direct,label=0.6,bend=30](A)(C)
\Edge[Direct,label=0.25,bend=20](C)(B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] that includes all packages and libraries necessary to compile your code?

Comment: hi, i added a minimal reproductable example, please see code at end of post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `positioning` library of tikz, you could create a dummy node below `A` at whatever distance you like and then draw the edge from this dummy node to `A`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Vertex[x=0,label=1, size=1.2]{A} 
\Vertex[x=3,size=1.2,label=2]{B} 
\Vertex[x=6,size=1.2,label=3]{C}
\node[below=1.5cm of A] (D) {};
\Edge[Direct,label=0.4,bend=20,fontscale=1.2](A)(B)
\Edge[Direct,label=0.6,bend=30](A)(C)
\Edge[Direct,label=0.25,bend=20](C)(B)
\Edge[Direct,label=0.25](D)(A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]